# Does Xcode 4.5 automatically set Retina Images

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, retina-display

How do I make the UIImage in Mainstoryboard turn to retina (I have two files for the image, I selected the retina image in UIImage setting). When I Launch my app it still not retina? Sorry if the question doesn't make sense.

Edit: Xcode does automatically set your Image to retina if you call your retina Image YourImageName@2x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you dont need to worry about retina images... Consider you have an image named **image.png**. You can use same image **"image.png"** in your **image view**. Now based on your **device content scale** it will pick **normal image i.e, image.png or retina image i.e., image@2x**. **Content scale is 2** for **iphone 4 and above**, **Others will use non-retina images**.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to set retina image, just name them as image.png and image@2x.png and set image.png as image in UIImageView, it automatically detects device and takes them accordingly.